# jquery parents/closest not working

Tags: jquery, parent, closest

I have a link which posts some data to a controller. It is working fine and updates the data. But I want to change the css of the parent div but it is not happening. I have tried a lot of variations but I must be doing something stupid.

The code is below

View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="added-property-excerpt">
        ...
        <div class="added-property-links">
        ...
        @if (!item.IsPropertyDisabled) { 
                @Html.ActionLink("Take off the Market" , "Disable", "Property", new { id = item.PropertyId }, new { id ="disable-link" })
            }
            else {
                @Html.ActionLink("Bring on the Market" , "Enable", "Property", new { id = item.PropertyId }, new { id ="enable-link" })
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

JQuery

```
 <script>
     $(function () {
         $('a#disable-link').click(function (e) {
             $('.added-property-links').text('loading...');
             $.ajax({
                 url: this.href,
                 dataType: "text json",
                 type: "POST",
                 data: {},
                 success: function (data, textStatus) { }
             });
             $(this).closest('.added-property-excerpt').css("background", "red");
          // $(this).parent('.added-property-excerpt').css("background", "red");
             e.preventDefault();
         });
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of the exported HTML?

Comment: Have you tied parents() instead of parent()

Comment: You are generating invalid markup. IDs must be unique.

Comment: what does the debugger / log say? could the ajax call throw an exception?

Comment: 'undefined' - thanks I didnt realise it .. as of now i just have one property so it didnt matter! will make them unique

Comment: @Ja͢ck You Legend!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function () {
    $('a#disable-link').click(function (e){
        var parentDiv=$(this).closest('.added-property-excerpt');
        $('.added-property-links').text('loading...');
        parentDiv.css("background", "red");
        $.ajax({...});
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

See the difference in [**a working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/KMzEU/1/) and [**non-working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/KMzEU/2/).

Comment: works perfectly... thanks. But can you tell me why the previous code was not working?

Comment: @Tripping, I think `$('.added-property-links').text('loading...');` line is clearing the `link/<a> tag` from the dom and `$(this)` was not able to reference it after that line.

Answer (score 5):

did you try:

```
$(this).parents('.added-property-excerpt').css("background", "red");
```

`parents` with an **s**.

What it does is that it goes from parent to parent until it find the class you want.

Comment: Good point. I've never used closest but I've now read the documentation. Thanks